# How to get names of json object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a data set

```
$scope.mydata = [{
    "Block_Devices": {
      "bdev0": {
        "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/ram1",
        "Capacity": "16777216",
        "Bytes_Written": 1577,
        "timestamp": "4365093970",
        "IO_Operations": 17757,
        "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
        "Bytes_Read": 17793,
        "Guest_IP_Address": "192.168.26.88"
      },
      "bdev1": {
        "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/ram2",
        "Capacity": "16777216",
        "Bytes_Written": 1975,
        "timestamp": "9365093970",
        "IO_Operations": 21380,
        "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
        "Bytes_Read": 20424,
        "Guest_IP_Address": "192.168.26.100"
      }
    },
    "Number of Devices": 2
  }]
```

and I would like to create a array from this json such as

```
devices = ['bdev0', 'bdev1']
```

when I try

`$scope.mydata.Block_Devices` it gives me the whole json object but I just want the names of the objects i.e bdev0 and bdev1 how can I get that?

Comment: `devices = Object.keys($scope.mydata[0].Block_Devices)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
var devices = [];

for (var key in $scope.mydata[0].Block_Devices) {
    devices.push(key) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case ES5 solution

```
devices = Object.keys($scope.mydata[0].Block_Devices)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the object properties to archive this:

```
var devices = [];
var data = $scope.mydata[0].Block_Devices;

for (var name in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    devices.push(name);
  }
}
```

The hasOwnProperty call is important to skip the properties which are from prototype, if you are sure that there are none, you can skip this.